# Attach array of photos with mailcore

Tags: objective-c, swift, mailcore2, mailcore

I need to attach an array of photos to an email using MailCore. I found the following code in another question, however I'm not sure how to apply this to the photos taken with the camera in my app.

My guess is that I have to get the filename of the photos and save them as strings to an array, and then attach the strings to the email by using the snippet of code.

```
NSArray *allAttachments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@{@"FilePathOnDevice": @"/var/mobile/etc..", @"FileTitle": @"IMG_0522.JPG"}, nil];
    for (int x = 0; x < allAttachments.count; x++) {
        NSString *attachmentPath = [[allAttachments objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"FilePathOnDevice"]];
        MCOAttachment *attachment = [MCOAttachment attachmentWithContentsOfFile:attachmentPath];
        [msgBuilder addAttachment:attachment];
    }
```

This is how I'm getting the photo using the camera

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    bedroomCells[lastSelectedIndex!.row].image = photo
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to save the UIImage returned by the image picker to a file before you can attach it.

Comment: Thank you, I used this method and was able to figure out the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving the image to the documents directory and using that file path to attach the image to mailcore.

Here is my code for the image picker:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    bedroomCells[lastSelectedIndex!.row].image = photo
    var photoLabel = bedroomCells[lastSelectedIndex!.row].text
    tableView.reloadData()

    //save photo to document directory
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 1.0)
    var imageFilePath = fileDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(photoLabel!).jpg")
    var imageFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
    imageData.writeToURL(imageFileURL!, atomically: false)
}
```

and the code for my mailcore method:

```
MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [fileDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *allAttachments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
for (int x = 0; x < allAttachments.count; x++) {
    NSString *attachmentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[allAttachments objectAtIndex:x]];
    MCOAttachment *attachment = [MCOAttachment attachmentWithContentsOfFile:attachmentPath];
    [builder addAttachment:attachment];
}
```

Comment: is there a way to convert to Swift?

Answer (score 0):

In swift code:

```
    var dataImage: NSData?
    dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)!
    var attachment = MCOAttachment()
    attachment.mimeType =  "image/jpg"
    attachment.filename = "image.jpg"
    attachment.data = dataImage
    builder.addAttachment(attachment)
```